# EmberAuth actionRedirectable Module prevents use from accessing a resource by URL

Tags: redirect, ember.js

I have the following Auth object in my app:

```
App.Auth = Ember.Auth.create
  signInEndPoint: '/users/sign_in'
  signOutEndPoint: '/users/sign_out'

  tokenKey: 'auth_token'
  tokenIdKey: 'user_id'

  userModel: 'App.User'

  modules: ['emberModel', 'rememberable', 'actionRedirectable']

  actionRedirectable:
    signInRoute: 'home'
    signOutRoute: 'login'

  rememberable:
    tokenKey: 'remember_token'
    period: 7
    autoRecall: true
```

Everything with authentication is working great. The problem I'm seeing now, though, is that when a user attempts to access, say, 'mydomain.com/#/articles/12' and has a valid remember token, accessing the application is tantamoun to starting a new boot of the application. The user is signed in via remember token, and actionRedirectable takes over and takes the user to HomeRoute instead of going to the requested resource.

I feel like I could get around this by manually transitioning the routes in the relvant login/logout controllers, but I wonder if there's a baked in way of solving this in EmberAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ember-auth](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com) dev here.

This looks like a known issue. Try the fix in [this comment from github issue #69](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth/issues/69#issuecomment-20432137).

In short, module order *does* matter. `actionRedirectable` needs to register the route (probably the `article` route in your case), before `rememberable` signs in the user and requests a redirect. Otherwise it would have nowhere to redirect to, and falls back to your `home` route as specified.

There have already been requests of fixing this unexpected behavior, but I haven't been able to find a fix yet - sorry.

Comment: I came here to add a bounty and found my question answered just in time! Thanks again for all your help. If I can think of anything I'll send you a Pull Request.